# Magento custom Upsell image not showing

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9.1

I have a problem where I can't get my custom attribute called `upsell` to get shown as my upsell image.

**Attribute information** 
**Attribute code:** upsell
**Scope:** Store View 
**Catalog Input type for store owner:** Media Image
**Apply To:** All product Types

I have created the thumbnail in the `skin/frontend/.../images/catalog/product/placeholder/`

Here's the code to show the image

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'upsell')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(150); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
```

If I change the `($_item, 'upsell')` to `($_item, 'thumbnail')` it's showing the right thumbnail.

Did I miss something in the process of creating the attribute?

Comment: make sure the attribute is Visible on Product View Page on Front-end

Comment: How do i ensure that it is that :)?

Comment: If i var_dump the product it doesn't have the value (like it does with image, thumbnail and so on)

Comment: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html most important option is `Visible on Catalog Pages on Front-end` did you select `yes` for this option? Do you have enabled lat catalog?

Comment: As it's a image, I dont have the option to select "VIsible on Catalog Pages on Front-end.
Not sure what you mean by lat catalog?

Comment: try to set the attribute scope to global. make sure reindex all indexes

Comment: @Zeedia the scope i have tried to change it all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ayTo call an image you can use: 
    $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'product_details_image')->resize()

and the full script is:

```php
<?php
$_detailsImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'product_details_image')->resize(); 

if ($_detailsImg != 'no_selection'):
    $_detailsImg ='<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'product_details_image')->resize().'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).' "/>';
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_detailsImg , 'product_details_image');
endif;

?>
```

Please change product_details_image to your attribute image code.

In case you don’t have image assigned to the product you will get this error : Image file was not found. in (var/ reports) 
so to fix this create an image with same name as the attribute code (product_details_image.jpg) to act as placeholder and add it to: 
skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/ 
Also you can add it to your skin folder. that is it.

**EDIT:**

I would rewrite the upsell.phtml again, get all ids add it to an array call product collections, filter by ids and you are ready to call any attribute including the media image - and I can confirm this works for me

**EDIT:**

This is may sound stupid but I can't find any other way, I had to load the collection for each product I hope some one can find other way.

I did try to call one collection and filter it using products IDs ( up sell products IDs ) but it didn't work.

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): 
    $items = $this->getItemCollection()->getItems();
    ?>
<div class="box-up-sell">
    <ul class="products-grid up-sell-grid">
        <?php foreach ($items as $item):  ?>
            <li class="item">
                <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId()); ?>
                <span><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></span>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'measurements_guide_image')->resize(200, 200); ?>" alt="">
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: My problem is that I did the same as you provided, but it still doesn't show up on my frontend, it's showing my thumbnail instead of the image selected on the backedn/adminpanel

Comment: And what does $_detailsImg refer to?

Comment: You could use this: $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId());
echo $_product->getMeasurementsGuideImage();

Comment: i Allready have the Model object, but the image isn't returning anything to me :(

Comment: I'll do it tonight and send it over

Comment: It is now working, the solution was as you said to load the products again.
It's a bit stupid but it's working now, which is the most important part :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this media attribute to product flat setting:

```
    <frontend>
    <product>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                  <upsell/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </product>
</frontend>
```

At this code  at my module config.xml  and then you need to reindex from  index management.

Comment: It didn't get the image to show, it's still showing the default image.